# How to convert decimal to hexadecimal and XOR of the hex string

Tags: c#, string, xor

I have an array of string (`string[]`) as a decimal number like `0, 0, 4, 142`, what I want to do is to convert that array to hexadecimal numbers like `0, 0, 4, 8e` and perform an XOR in the C#, but I am not getting *expected XOR*,

Code:

```
public CheckSumHelper(string[] array)
{
  this._array = array.Select(x => Convert.ToInt64(x, 16)).ToArray();
}

public string GetCheckSum()
{
   long xor = this._array.Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
   return xor.ToString("X");
}
```

Comment: If the initial number is decimal you shouldn't parse it as hexadecimal.

Comment: but then it gives me the wrong Xor!

Comment: You should not treat number (e.g. `142`) as *hexadecimal*: `Convert.ToInt64(x)` not `Convert.ToInt64(x, 16)` (in you cuurent code `Convert.ToInt64("142", 16)` returns `322` and you have wrong outcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `142` is a *decimal* (not *hexadecimal*) number (you don't treat `0x142 == 332`), drop `16` in `Convert.ToInt64(...)`:

```
 public static string GetCheckSum(string[] array) {
   // TODO: validate array here (it must be not null, not empty etc.)

   return array
     .Select(item => Convert.ToInt64(item)) // initial number is decimal           
     .Aggregate((s, item) => s ^ item) 
     .ToString("X");                        // we want final result being hexadecimal
 }
```

And so you'll have `0 ^ 0 ^ 4 ^ 142 == 138 == 0x8A`.

**Edit:** When working with formats let computer explain what's going on:

```
private static string GetCheckSumExplained(string test) {
  string[] array = test.Split(',');

  // Routine under test - GetCheckSum 
  string result = GetCheckSum(array);
  // Convert string back to long in order to represent it as binary and decimal
  long resultAsInt = Convert.ToInt64(result, 16);

  string args = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array
    .Select(item => Convert.ToInt64(item))
    .Select(item => $"{Convert.ToString(item, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')} : {item,3} : 0x{item.ToString("X2")}"));

  return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
     args,
    "---------------------",
   $"{Convert.ToString(resultAsInt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')} : {resultAsInt,3} : 0x{result.PadLeft(2, '0')}");
}

...

string test = "0,0,4,20,15,142,0,8,179,141,0, 8, 181, 141, 0,8"; 

Console.Write(GetCheckSumExplained(test));
```

**Outcome:**

```
00000000 :   0 : 0x00
00000000 :   0 : 0x00
00000100 :   4 : 0x04
00010100 :  20 : 0x14
00001111 :  15 : 0x0F
10001110 : 142 : 0x8E
00000000 :   0 : 0x00
00001000 :   8 : 0x08
10110011 : 179 : 0xB3
10001101 : 141 : 0x8D
00000000 :   0 : 0x00
00001000 :   8 : 0x08
10110101 : 181 : 0xB5
10001101 : 141 : 0x8D
00000000 :   0 : 0x00
00001000 :   8 : 0x08
---------------------
10011111 : 159 : 0x9F
```

So we have `9F`. If you are sure that the right answer is `B1` you should examine your data or/and formula

**Edit 2:** If initial `string` looks like (see comments)

```
 00$00$04$20$15$8e$00$08$b3$8d$00$08$b5$8d$00$08
```

we can implement `GetCheckSum` as

```
 // Now we're working with item_1$Item_2$...$Item_N
 public static string GetCheckSum(string value) {
   // TODO: Validate string here

   return value
     .Split('$')
     .Select(item => Convert.ToInt64(item, 16)) // 16 is required in this format
     .Aggregate((s, item) => s ^ item)
     .ToString("X");
 }

 ...

 string test = "00$00$04$20$15$8e$00$08$b3$8d$00$08$b5$8d$00$08";

 // Let's have a look on the the array
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", test
                   .Split('$')
                   .Select(item => Convert.ToInt64(item, 16))));

 Console.Wrire(GetCheckSum(test));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 0, 0, 4, 32, 21, 142, 0, 8, 179, 141, 0, 8, 181, 141, 0, 8
 B1
```

Comment: decimal values: `0,0,4,20,15,142,0,8,179,141,0, 8, 181, 141, 0,8` expecting `b1` but returns `9F`

Comment: Why do you expect B1? I get 9F when I xor all these values in my calculator.

Comment: @tkausl so I want to convert those values in hex for ex: `142` is `8e`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I got that. But XORing the values still results in 9F.

Comment: @tkausl this is how hex string looks like:`00$00$04$20$15$8e$00$08$b3$8d$00$08$b5$8d$00$08`

Comment: When I am reading data it look like: `0,0,4,20,15,142,0,8,179,141,0, 8, 181, 141, 0,8`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale you haven't converted all of your values to Hex, such as 20 -> 0x14

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale: So you are reading data in *wrong way*: it should be `0, 0, 4, 32...` Please, notice, that `0x20 == 32` (you have *hexadecimal* `20` in the initial data)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that's the big miss event `15 == 21`!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale It’s important to realize that hexadecimal is still and integer/number.  It is merely a different formatting.  They represent the same thing.

Comment: @Chris but in the case of `Xor` will they produce the same output?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Just one question --> Is it ok to get the value from constructor? or method's inputs param is good way?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference between the data stored, merely how it’s presented to the viewer.  10 == 0x0A == binary 1010

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale: if instance you are creating *requires* the value (i.e. instance without the value is *invalid*) than get the value via constructor; if value is *auxiliary* one - put it via corresponding method.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I've been looking at your data, and based on the fact that you're trying to calculate a checksum (something I've done a lot working with RS232 devices) and your data and expected value, I believe that you are calculating your checksum wrong and that you really want the two's compliment of the lower 8-bits of the sum of your data.

The sum of your data is 847 (or 0x34F).  The lower 8 bits are 0x4F.  The two's compliment is `0xFF ^ 0x4F + 1 = 0xB1`

Comment: @Chris Thanks, request to post as answer for more clarification

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I modified my previous answer to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

The `Convert.ToInt64(string,int)` method specifies the base of your string input.  You're converting "142" to 0x142, not 0x8e.

Just use `Convert.ToInt64(string)`.

As far as the XOR issue you may be having, see this post: [xor with 3 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228252/xor-with-3-values)

Based on the data you've provided and the idea that you're calculating a checksum I suspect that what you actually need to do is provide a Longitudinal Redundancy Check.  The easiest way to do this is:

`(SumOfAllData & 0xFF) ^ 0xFF + 1`

The act of flipping all the bits in a number and adding 1 is also known as the two's compliment.

Example Code:

```
private int CalcChecksum(int[] array)
{
    int Sum = array.Aggregate(0, (total, value) => total += value);
    return ((Sum & 0xFF) ^ 0xFF) + 1;
}
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I posted an example.  Note that this uses only the lower 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks will look into this. If I want to convert back the decimal `142` to `0x8E` and pass as a byte?