# Determine difference with logic operators

Tags: c#, boolean, logic

I have this line of code

```
bool b1 = true;
bool b2 = true;
bool b3 = true;

bool areDifferent = b1 ^ b2 ^ b3;
```

which works, if there are only 2 booleans `(true XOR true) // false`

but it doesn't work with n booleans `(true XOR true XOR true) // true`

Question: What is the correct generic way to determine if all values are equal (or are not)  with C# logic operators (AND, OR, XOR, XNOR)

Comment: Why are you limited to logic operators? I would just use `==`, or LINQ if there are really a lot of values.

Comment: why do you want to check them explicitly with logic operators, anyway? my first attempt to check for equality would be to test if the AND of all of them is true, _or_ the OR of all of them is false.

Comment: @Sweeper with `==` you have the same problem - `false == false == false // false`

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228252/xor-with-3-values) is a very similar question

Comment: (with LINQ, i'd use `myBoolList.Distinct().Count()==1`)

Comment: @MongZhu I need a generic approach, not 3

Comment: just loop your bools and do a `&&` with the previous result as if you would sum them up.: `bool b = mybools.First(); foreach(var b1 in myBools.Skip(1)) b &= b1;`.

Comment: `true XOR true` will result in false and that will be XORed with `true` which will return true. Isn't it the right logic ?

Comment: althugh the dupe is about 3 values, there are answers for multiple ones. Just read carefully.

Comment: Franz's solution adjusted to your requirement (inverted logic): https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBc4QO

Comment: The Dupe is about a ternary XOR, which needs exactly one Boolean to be true.
This question is asking about seeing if 3 values are the same, which is a different problem. The 2 problems are only equivalent with 2 values.

Comment: @HimBromBeere this is a totally different question. I would also accept other logic operators instead of `XOR` only because one answer seems to fit, doesn't make this a duplicate

Comment: sure... otherwise you´d never get a chance of a dupe as no two questions are completely similar. They of course allways have some differences. however many different questions have the same answer. Anyway: does the link answer your question or not?

Comment: @HimBromBeere closing this question doesn't give me the chance to get a better anser than that in the other question - I feel there is a better way to solve this

Comment: Then clearify why you consider the dupe to be not helpful. Why does it not answer your question. How is yours different so that the link does not apply here?

Comment: being a dupe does not make your question **bad**. It´s perfectly **valid**. It justs provides you a list of ansers to a similar problem. So the only remaining point is: did you got the answer for yours? If so, everything is fine, IMHO. Otherwise clearfiy why it does not answer your specific problem.

Comment: See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6228470/2528063 which **is** exactly for your case of n values.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that solves the problem with linq but not with logic operators (what this question is about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, if you insist on a solution the has to use a logical operator, here is a solution using the XOR operator to check whether there is at least one item deifferent from the rest:

```
public bool IsAnyValueDifferentFromRest(params bool [] values)
{
    if (values.Any() == false)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    
    bool stillSame = values.First();
    
    foreach (var boolValue in values.Skip(1)) // stole the skip part from HimBrombeere
    {
        // at the first difference you find you can exit
        if (stillSame ^ boolValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple opportunities, the easiest is is a simple LINQ-statement:

```
var allEqual = myBools.Distinct().Count == 1;
```

Alternativly loop your values:

```
bool AllSame(IEnumerable<bool> bools)
{
    var b1 = myBools.First();
    foreach(var b = myBools.Skip(1))
        if(b != b1)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or also using only logical operators:

Be aware that you should materialize the collection using `ToArray` or `ToList` to avoid multiple iterations of the same collections.

Comment: Or you can just `foreach` and store the first value to compare to, by having another `bool` that says `isFirst` or use `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

I would go:

```
bool b1 = true;
bool b2 = true;
bool b3 = true;

bool areSame = (b1 && b2 && b3) || !(b1 || b2 || b3);
```

If they are all true the AND part will return true.
Otherwise it will return false.

If they are all false, the OR part will return false and NOT will cause it to return true.
Otherwise the OR part returns true and the NOT will cause it to return false.

So if they are all 1 or all 0, it will return true.

If you want it the other way, negate it.

To make it work any value rather than just Boolean values, you can use bitwise operators

```
bool areDifferent = (bool) ~((b1 & b2 & b3) | ~(b1 | b2 | b3))
```

In this case, the & statement will produce a 1 where the bit is all 1. The ~| statement will provide a 1 where the bit is all 0.
ORing the 2 parts will then give you a value which is all 1 if the values are the same.
Negating that will give you all 0 (and thus logical false) if the values are all the same.

This can be extended by simply throwing in as may values as needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you add the code for your approach?

Comment: I have converted the examples given to code samples.